# Resizing Images on a Rich Text Field

Tags: richtextarea

Is it possible to resize images in a Rich Text Field?

We need to add images to a rich text field we have, but we found out we couldn't do any resizing.

Is resizing possible in Salesforce rich text field? Or is this a limitation?

Edit:
This is the rich text editor that I see:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with Apex.
If you have only 1 image in the text you can use the following sample code.

```
String contactId;
Contact c = [
        SELECT Id, Picture__c
        FROM Contact
        WHERE Id = :contactId
];

c.Picture__c = c.Picture__c.replace('<img', '<img style="height: 256px"');

update contacts;
```

*Note*: update SObject name and field name

If you have more than 1 image you might want to add better search strings

Comment: Presumably that is lost if further interactive editing is done?

Comment: No, for some reason it is saved. Even when you update the content of the field

Comment: Good to know - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer from **ytiq** was excellent, and really helped me solve a similar problem.

What I found is that if his code gets run multiple times, it will add multiple copies of the "style="height: XXX" tag, and the first one added will take precedence over any subsequent ones.

Pasted below is some more elaborate code that takes care of that issue:

```
    public static void resizeProfilePhoto(integer pixelsWide, string contactID) {
    Contact c = [
        SELECT Id, Profile_Photo__c
        FROM Contact
        WHERE Id = :contactId
    ];
    if (c.Profile_Photo__c != null) {
        //system.debug('field before ' + c.Profile_Photo__c);
        string newTag = '<img style="height: ' + pixelsWide + 'px"';
        if (c.Profile_Photo__c.startsWith('<p><img style="height:')) {
            c.Profile_Photo__c = c.Profile_Photo__c.replaceFirst('<img style="height: [0-9]*px;"', newTag);
            system.debug('Found existing size - field after ' + c.Profile_Photo__c);
        } else {
            c.Profile_Photo__c = c.Profile_Photo__c.replace('<img', newTag);
            system.debug('field after ' + c.Profile_Photo__c);
        }
        update c;
    }
}
```