# Resize lightning input rich text image

Tags: lightning-web-components, images

I am using lightning-input-rich-text component to compose emails within Salesforce. I am able to insert/ copy-paste an image but couldnt resize it. As per [lightning-input-rich-text documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-rich-text/documentation), it is not possible to resize the image but wondering if anyone tried a work around for it ?

I could hack around the img tag within the input body but I couldnt achieve the on-screen resize border something like :
[image]

instead adding the image shows like this without the border :

[image]

Any hack around adding the resizable border will be really appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per [salesforce doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-rich-text/documentation), Resizing of images is not supported. Copy and pasting of images is not supported, although it might work on some combinations of browsers and operating systems.

You are left with few options:-

1. change the value received from onchange handler and add the size attribute in client side or [server side](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279364/resizing-images-on-a-rich-text-field)
2. Using some third party editor which allows the resizing of the image in the editor

Comment: maybe I could use quillJs which Salesforce uses lol.. I was thinking in the same lines too. 
I can change the size in client side , but doing that in a nicer UX way seem impossible as I couldnt get the borders

Comment: @RahulBoinepally yes you can go for quillJs.

Comment: @RahulBoinepally did you managed to do it with Quill Js?

Comment: sorry for the delay, I have used ckeditor as an Iframe in a vfpage, embedded in an LWC comp as I couldnt get images resized using quill

Comment: @RahulBoinepally can you share your implementation with CKEDITOR? Did you use that to edit image then push that content to the RichText field in SF?

Comment: Has anyone tried this with Quill? https://github.com/Fandom-OSS/quill-blot-formatter?tab=readme-ov-file

Comment: @dschueler - sorry cannot share the code, but I have created a VF page which renders the ckeditor and then used the vf inside the LWC comp rendered as iframe. I also used the window.postMessage to send the events/ data bw LWC and VF. 
Quill didnt work as they dont support image resize.